goo.gl is closing down
goo.gl, a URL shortener service from Google, is shutting down, and in one year it will no longer work: https://news.slashdot.org/story/24/07/18/216211/google-url-shortener-links-will-return-a-404-response . All links using goo.gl on MO will need to be updated.
When searching on MO for goo.gl I get 8 results in questions/answers, which can be edited, but there are more in the comments like this one, and those cannot be edited by normal users.
[EDIT: a better search by Martin Sleziak returns about 55 hits on MO including comments.]
How should we handle this migration?

Can you link to a search query that finds all the goo.gl links including comments? If there's not a massive amount of them in comments they can be edited by hand by mods. I won't edit the one you point out now, that seems to be an example where the user just wrote the url and the system turned it into a hyperlink. In cases where the link might in the markdown (eg [link text](https://goo.gl/example)) it's less clear how to find these.

@DavidRoberts I have no idea how to search for goo.gl in link targets either. This Google query finds goo.gl in the text, including comments, but if it's behind Markdown I don't know how to find it. In fact, there might be more instances in questions and answers, too, for the same reason.

Thanks for that, it's a start. I'm sure Martin Sleziak will turn up at some point with a SEDE query or two to find a bunch of non-obvious things.

In case they might be useful, some searches and SEDE queries are in the MO editors' lounge.

Thanks Martin! Very helpful. I have added a link to those searches.

@DavidRoberts, re, what's the logic behind not editing a bare link vs. a link in []() syntax?  In either case it's clearly meant to be used as a link, and will become useless once the switch happens.

@LSpice it's not about editing them or not, but finding them. Plain text search won't find links using the shorter url inside Markdown. They should all be edited or otherwise the working link provided (as I found in my first edit, the bare url made the comment too long to post!)

@DavidRoberts, re, I understand why finding them could be difficult (although I guess that is resolved by @‍MartinSleziak's queries linked above).  I meant to refer instead to "I won't edit the one you point out now, that seems to be an example where the user just wrote the url and the system turned it into a hyperlink." from your original comment.  (Maybe the emphasis was on "now", as in "it can be handled automatically later"?)

@LSpice yes, I meant I wasn't going to do it right now (at the time of writing), in case someone else (another mod) felt motivated to do it before me.

How much internet rot is Google about to unleash with this

@DavidRoberts You are right, one of the reasons that we have this problem is that users had to use a URL shortener because the comment was too long. Several feature requests to exclude URLs in hyperlinks when counting comment length exist on [meta.se]; they are typically marked as duplicates of this question, so I guess that's the one we have to upvote. I have just edited its text to make it clear that the feature request includes hyperlinks.

A recent post on [meta.se]: Goo.gl links will stop working on August 25, 2025, which will break them in posts.
